# Sudden problem with amd dc?

Tags: boot, amdgpu

So last week my PC ran into a very curious problem. My rig is as follows:

- AMD Ryzen 5 2600
- Gigabyte B450MM DS3H
- Gigabyte RX580

Just using ubuntu 18.10 casually, my display server seemed to crash. Hard resetting was the only way out, so I did just that. Afterwards, my PC booted to a black screen. Listening to my PC, everything seemed to work normally however.

I remembered doing an update (**not** to 19.04, mind you), so to test the problem I booted a secondary Ubuntu partition (18.04). And color me surprised: I had the same error! I even ran into the same error on a live disk.

Windows still works fine.

I fixed the error after adding a kernel value in grub: `amdgpu.dc=0`

My question is: how could this error have arisen so suddenly, even on a live disk. Is my video card going bad?

Secondary question: what does AMD's DC really do? What am I missing out on disabling it?

Thanks in advance for your patience!

Comment: Just to add -- I have the same effect today. My system booted with a black screen and was solved by amdgpu.dc=0. The cpu is an AMD A6-9500 RADEON R5. Running kernal 5.3.0-46 on Ubuntu Budgie 19.10; The system also had 18.04 installed as dual bot and this had the same problem. The only hardware change was that my son has "borrowed" my webcam